# What will happen if we install magento 2 from github and later used composer to update

Tags: magento2, composer, github

Recently i am working on a Magento 2 website which `was installed from github ,` when i started to work on that project `i used composer` as when while installing on my local machine it asks me to `run "composer install"`

But i am not able to do so , even after running composer install again it asks me to run the same command.

My question now is

> what is the `difference between the different methods to install the magento 2

and their cons if in future `we ulter the method to update` or while installing any extension.

I read this [How to get the Magento software](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html)

> If you clone the Magento 2 GitHub repository, you cannot use the Magento software in a production environment. You cannot have a live store that accepts orders and so on.
>   Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It will not update Magento, only the external dependencies, listed in the  `require` section of `composer.json`. Everything in the `replace` section is supposed to be in the repository itself, so composer does not install it.